# jQuery Tabs causes problems in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs with jQuery 1.3.2 run locally.
The tabs get created just fine, but IE tells me that the site is running content that could be a security risk (which is annoying, but maybe that's what always happens when IE sees any javascript...I wouldn't know because I don't use IE).
Anyway, I have 3 tabs, and whenever the user goes to the 3rd tab and then back to either of the first two, IE hangs and then tells me I have to close IE, at which point it immediately reopens the page with the "Blocked Content" warning again and tells me that it "recovered" the tab.

My tabs work flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome on Windows and OS X...but not in IE.

Is this a known issue?  Anyone run across this before?

**EDIT**

Code can be seen [here](http://www.jamespwright.com/testing/installprocess/)

Comment: Can you post the html/script running?

Comment: Not getting any kind of warning here. You might check your IE security settings (Im under an ISA proxy and firewall, which is already picky enough). Also, check if all javascript referenced is under the same domain and uses relative paths.

Comment: no problems here either.  
if i put my settings to high the tabs don't display(i think it disables javascript).  medium-high they work fine.

Comment: Tried it on my coworkers pc as well.  We are both running Windows 7 with IE8, it happens to both of us.